# Calculating distance between many users of a handful of facilities, a small hangup

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, network-analyst, route

I am trying to calculate distance between thousands of people and a handful of facilities.  I know the ArcGIS ROUTENAME issue has been addressed many times in forums.  I have scoured them and am hung up on one point.

In this thread (https://geonet.esri.com/thread/88593) it is stated that "You might have to load multiple copies of the same park because multiple people use the same park."  Exactly.  In my case, these are facilities.

In this thread (https://geonet.esri.com/message/233312#233312) it is stated that "...your 368 locations are repeating. You could do this with some relates...".  Yes, I need to repeat locations (facilities), but there is not direction on how to use relates to generate repeated locations.

I need to figure out how to make hundreds of duplicate copies of the same facility.  Once duplicated, I will then give each one of the hundreds of copies of the same facility a unique ID.  Then I can match the facility to the thousands of users of it using ROUTENAME.

It is just duplicating the facility that is hanging me up.

Comment: You will probably get better help if you cut out most of your question and get to,  "How do I create duplicate points?"

Comment: That doesn't seem like a terribly efficient way to perform that analysis (though maybe it is). Two alternatives would be to break up your data and use a Closest Facility solver (see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124445/), or make sure your people records have an attribute that says what facility they go to, run the OD Cost Matrix tool and get all the routes, then filter down to just the pairings you want (see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126639/ for the general principle, though that's considering a NEAR analysis - concept is the same though).

Comment: If you really do want to just duplicate those points, a Join and Export (won't do the multiple points until it's been exported, and must be in a feature class and not a shapefile for it to work; see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123064/) or the Make Query Table tool should be able to quickly duplicate the facility points the number of times needed for their corresponding people points.

Answer (score 1):

If your real problem is to measure the distance between X and Y, you can use OD Cost matrix.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00470000004r000000

Edit: It doesn't generate routes but adds distances calculated from routes to the output table.

Comment: OD Cost Matrix cannot generate route lines. It can only generate straight lines between O/Ds or no lines at all. See the Tip under the first image and the section near the bottom called Output shape type in the help file you linked to.

Comment: @ChrisW You are right, I edited my comment.