# Can I join a table with a field with several rows with the same word to a polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins

I have a table that looks like:

```
Name
X
X
X
Y
Y
Z
Z
```

I have a polygon feature class with the attributes:

```
Place
X
Y
Z
```

Essentially, I want to join that table to the polygon, but I want each row in the table to be kept.
When I attempt a join, it only joins to one x, y, z and not all.

I am using ArcMap.

Comment: Is the data the same in all the X's, Y's, Z's? Can the field names be changed in your table?

Comment: No, data in each row is different. Each row has data by a different person but in the same area (X) polygon. I want to provide each of those rows that area as they are different records.

Comment: I don't know of a way to join multiple fields to a single field. I think you could do it by breaking the table into three different tables (one for Person 1, Person 2, etc.) instead of keeping the fields (X1, X2, etc.).

Comment: would a "relate" help you ? It depends what you want to do after. Otherwise, you need to duplicate your polygons (=> you will have geometric overlaps)

Comment: @radouxju I tried a relate but I would prefer a join in this scenario. Though I'm afraid multiple polygons looks like it might be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

@radouxju is correct - it's either a relate or duplicate geometry, and those are your choices. You can duplicate the geometry most easily with the [Make Query Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006r000000) tool. If your version of Arc is recent enough (10.1 or higher I think?) *and* you're working in a geodatabase, you can do a Join *followed by an export of the result* and that should give you everything with a polygon for each row in your table. Note that the multiples don't show up until you export, as you've seen just looking at the join result only shows first returned match.

See [ArcMap many-to-many join](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123064/arcmap-many-to-many-join/123114#123114)